# How to instantiate an io.TextIOWrapper object with a name attribute?

Tags: python, stream, stdout, stdin

```py
import sys

print(sys.stdin)
print(type(sys.stdin))
print(sys.stdin.name)
print(sys.stdin.__dict__)
```

When the above is executed, the following is the output:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
<stdin>
{'mode': 'r'}
```

So from the above snippet and output, I can see that `name` is an attribute to the `_io.TextIOWrapper` instance representing `sys.stdin`. And from the documentation on `io.TextIOWrapper` (via `$ pydoc io.TextIOWrapper` for ex.), it does list `name` as a data descriptor. However for whatever reason, `name` doesn't show up as an item in its `__dict__`.

When I create an instance of `io.TextIOWrapper` manually using for example:

```py
import io

a = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BytesIO())
print(a)
a.name
```

`<_io.TextIOWrapper encoding='UTF-8'>` is printed. But the `a.name` line throws the error: `AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'name'`; the `AttributeError` I expected, but I didn't it expect to say it was an `_io.BytesIO` object.

I'd then tried creating a subclass and attaching a `name` attribute manually, like so:

```py
import io


class NamedTextIOWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):

    def __init__(self, buffer, name=None, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        io.TextIOWrapper.__init__(self, buffer, **kwargs)


input = io.BytesIO('abc')
stdin = NamedTextIOWrapper(input, name='<stdin>', encoding='utf-8')

print(stdin.name)
```

However this runs into: `AttributeError: attribute 'name' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects is not writable`.

Ideally, I'd also like to be able to maintain the `mode` attribute seemingly available in the `sys.stdin` instance in a manually instantiated `io.TextIOWrapper` object as well. And also for the `sys.stdout` equivalent, which I assume would be just the same except the `name` should just be set to `'<stdout>'` and the `mode` to `'w'`.

Comment: Why do you need a custom name attribute for the `TextIOWrapper` object in the first place?

Comment: I'm actually trying to fix this bug: https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/1064

Comment: @blhsing and having a name attribute would solve this problem. The problem occurs in sec/click/testing.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `__getattribute__` method with one that returns the `name` key of the object's attribute dictionary when the `name` attribute is requested:

```
class NamedTextIOWrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self, buffer, name=None, **kwargs):
        vars(self)['name'] = name
        super().__init__(buffer, **kwargs)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'name':
            return vars(self)['name']
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

so that:

```
input = io.BytesIO(b'abc')
stdin = NamedTextIOWrapper(input, name='<stdin>', encoding='utf-8')
print(stdin.name)
```

outputs:

```
<stdin>
```